# Interview Questions: Exception within Event Handler

Tags: c#, .net, events, exception

1) You have 10 Subscribers to an event in your .NET application. Once you invoke the event, do the subscribers get notified synchronously or asynchronously?

2) You have 10 Subscribers to an event in your .NET application.  Now one event handler has a bad code and it throws an exception.  Do the other nine event handlers still continue?

Thanks,

Comment: wouldn't it be quicker just to fire up a quick test app and try it?

Comment: It is not about the outcome. I know the outcome. It is about explaining this behaviour in detail due an interview question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> You have 10 Subscribers to an event in
>   your application. Once you invoke the
>   event, do the subscribers get notified
>   synchronously or asynchronously?

It depends on how the publisher "invokes" the event. In the typical case (e.g. a C# field-like event), the handlers are just members of the invocation-list of a multicast delegate. Invoking the "event" is equivalent to invoking the backing *delegate*, which in turn is morally equivalent to invoking each of its individual members sequentially. So once could view an invocation such as:

```
MyEvent(this, myEventArgs);
```

as *similar* to:

```
foreach(EventHandler handler in myEventDelegate.GetInvocationList())
    handler(this, myEventArgs);
```

It's just a sequence of delegate invocations: the subscribers are notified **synchronously**. Of course, the publisher can choose to invoke the event *any way it pleases*, so it needn't do it this way - it may well use the thread-pool (QUWI / BeginInvoke) or any other mechanism that produces asynchronous notifications.

> You have 10 Subscribers to an event in
>   your application. Now one event
>   handler has a bad code and it throws
>   an exception. Do the other nine event
>   handlers still continue?

Again, it depends. In the typical (aforementioned) case, the answer is **no**, because exceptions are not being handled on a per-subscriber basis. If a handler throws, the remainder of the "foreach" is abandoned. Of course, there's nothing to stop a publisher from wrapping the invocation of each handler in a try-catch (ignore) block, or use any other mechanism to ensure that all the handlers are invoked.

Answer (score 4):

1. [Synchronously, by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It is possible to [invoke asynchronousl](http://shiman.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/c-net-delegates-asynchronous-invocation-begininvoke-method/)y, however.
2. No, the exception will bubble to to the event source - which will crash. Again, it's possible to [change that behavior](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/events_fundamentals.aspx) by invoking each handler separately in a try/catch.

Comment: I'd be wary of invoking each handler in a try/catch. I mean, you can't guarantee you know who has subscribed to your event (assuming it's publicly exposed somehow), so assuming you know enough about your subscribers to catch whatever they might throw seems like a bad idea to me. I'd be interested to see other opinions.

Comment: The link to async has a comment pointing to http://www.lukepuplett.com/2009/05/using-delegates-oh-for-f-sake-moment.html which is worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

1) No threading. Methods (subscribers) are executed synchronous.

2) It depends. The remaining subscribers will not be executed unless the exception is handled. An exception always halts the code/thread immediately unless handled. This means that if 2 of 10 subscribing methods has been executed when the exception occurs then the remaning 8 will not be executed.

Events are simply lists of methods to be invoked. .Net does this for you behind the scenes.

Comment: If you meant to say that the subscribers are executed sequentially, the correct is to say they're synchronous.

Comment: @Martinho: Thanks! Going to bed... *zzzz*